# Wamp Error:#2002. I do not have access to myphpadmin.

Tags: php, wamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access Denied when opening phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702051/access-denied-when-opening-phpmyadmin)

**#2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).**

I just installed wamp and it is giving me this error when I try and access "myphpadmin".

Below is my configuration file of config.inc.php from C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.5.1

```
<?php

/* Servers configuration */
$i = 0;

/* Server: localhost [1] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

/* End of servers configuration */

$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en-utf-8';
$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';


/* rajk - for blobstreaming */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_garbage_threshold'] = 50;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_repository_threshold'] = '32M';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_temp_blob_timeout'] = 600;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_temp_log_threshold'] = '32M';


?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1st suggestion: make sure mysql is actually running.  2nd suggestion: make sure your firewall isn't blocking it.

Comment: It looks like that you're not the only one having that problem: [Access Denied when opening phpMyAdmin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702051/access-denied-when-opening-phpmyadmin). **Please add your `mysql.log` to your question** (If it is the same as in the linked question that is not necessary, then just say it is the same)