# MySQL service is not starting up in Windows

Tags: mysql

```
FROM C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\Data\purplista.err:

121226 13:12:06  [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.

121226 13:12:06  InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled

121226 13:12:06  InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions

121226 13:12:06  InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3

121226 13:12:06  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 107.0M

121226 13:12:06  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool

121226 13:12:06  InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
```

I am facing the above issue while starting Mysql from mySql workbench. If I start it from windows services it got stopped automatically in few seconds.

**Note:** If I uninstall and re-install it wrks for sometime but thing after few days I am facing this issue again

Could any one help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Do you know what is the working folder of the service, and what command line is sent to mysqld?

Answer (score 0):

For

```
121226 13:12:06  InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
```

you can try set `innodb_use_sys_malloc = 0` in `my.cnf`. More reference documentation is [here](http://www.innodb.com/doc/innodb_plugin-1.0-doc-single/innodb-plugin.html#innodb-performance-use_sys_malloc).

Also:

- you can try clear contents of `mysql-bin.index`. Related question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702051/access-denied-when-opening-phpmyadmin).
- if you have some antivirus/firewall software, try turn it off and check the functionality, bec. it can be the reason of some issues.

Answer (score -1):

What i think the problem might be is .

1. give MySql access to the firewall fix this
2. you should allow MySQL server (mysqld.exe) to start and allow access
   to port 3306.
3. Try to decrease innodb_buffer_pool_size in my.ini file then. Set it
   to 1G and check if this will allow service to start.

`note` mysql uses tcp connection

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply!! I have turned off firewall in my machine though i ma facing the issue.

Comment: @VijayM check the last one also

Comment: I made the the changes as you suggested but its not yet resolved